# use sed to match regex on infinite lines and dump matched result in another file

Tags: regex, awk, sed

```
I, [2014-05-06T06:41:40.742048 #1140]  INFO -- : Processing by RegistrationsController#create as */*
I, [2014-05-06T06:41:40.742246 #1140]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "user"=>{"firstname"=>"...", "lastname"=>"...", "userdetail"=>{"company_name"=>"..."}, "email"=>"...", "confirm_email"=>"...", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "userdetail"=>{"stripe_card_token"=>"tok_103z0G2C7pqlpkF2EMnce0fP", "ccName"=>"...", "ccNumber"=>"[FILTERED]", "ccCode"=>"[FILTERED]", "street_address1"=>"...", "street_address2"=>"", "city"=>"...", "state_code"=>"...", "zipcode"=>"...", "country_code"=>"..."}, "date"=>{"month"=>"..", "year"=>".."}}
D, [2014-05-06T06:41:40.745900 #1140] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session Load (1.2ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT `sessions`.* FROM `sessions` WHERE `sessions`.`session_id` = 'a7fcdd2176e490998cf0b85a71f4f0d5' ORDER BY `sessions`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1^[[0m
I, [2014-05-06T06:41:40.783411 #1127]  INFO -- : Started GET "/invoices/067c84a2-f40e-47dc-bacc-08a48e5cc72e" for 201.102.245.18 at 2014-05-06 06:41:40 +0000
I, [2014-05-06T06:41:40.787649 #1127]  INFO -- : Processing by InvoicesController#show as HTML
I, [2014-05-06T06:41:40.787746 #1127]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"uid"=>"067c84a2-f40e-47dc-bacc-08a48e5cc72e"}
D, [2014-05-06T06:41:40.794223 #1127] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session Load (1.0ms)^[[0m  SELECT `sessions`.* FROM `sessions` WHERE `sessions`.`session_id` = 'f7b35a977fe056dc37bf8f296daa1a9b' ORDER BY `sessions`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
D, [2014-05-06T06:41:40.952192 #1127] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mCACHE (0.0ms)^[[0m  SELECT `statuses`.* FROM `statuses` WHERE `statuses`.`id` = 17 ORDER BY `statuses`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
I, [2014-05-06T06:41:40.994466 #1127]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 207ms (Views: 75.1ms | ActiveRecord: 119.3ms)
D, [2014-05-06T06:41:40.995972 #1127] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36m (0.8ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mBEGIN^[[0m
D, [2014-05-06T06:41:40.997475 #1127] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35m (0.7ms)^[[0m  COMMIT
I, [2014-05-06T06:41:41.813041 #1140]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 1070ms (Views: 0.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

the above is the part of the logs from which I want to get the value of "stripe_card_token". But only when the following conditions are satisfied,

1. get the process ID(#1140 in above example) of the line which contains 'RegistrationsController#create'
2. get 'tok_.*' from the line with second occurrence of process ID(#1140) (second line in above example)
3. Write above 'tok_.*' to a file if the line with fourth occurrence of process ID(#1140) contains 'Completed 200 OK' (last line in above example)

I tried grep but i wasn't to do this, then tried awk and learnt it doesn't support backreference, then now im trying to get this done by sed.

EDIT:
so far what I got,

```
sed -ne '/[[:digit:]]+]/{h;p}
/RegistrationsController#create/p
/tok_.*",/{h;p}' file
```

I think the above will give me the tok_id if its in Paramters of RegistrationsController#create.. and for the check of Completed 200 I will have to modify the third expression. Anyone know the correct way?

Comment: `data | sed -E '/regex/'`

Comment: Awk is an apparently Turing-complete programming language. The trick is not to try to do it in a single regular expression.

Comment: "check if the line with the fourth occurrence" doesn't sound robust.  You want to collect the token from successful transactions, right?

Comment: Completed 200 is returned in both cases, successful/unsuccessful transaction.
if the transaction is unsuccessful then the fourth occurrence of process ID contains 'Completed 200'
else there can be around 25/30 occurrence of process ID before getting 'Completed 200'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an awk version that passes through the log file 3 times.

1. Get the process ID.
2. Count how many lines have the process ID. If the 4th one is Completed 200 OK, we can extract the token.
3. If Step 2 was successful, get the token from the parameters line.

File `gettoken.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
  count=0;
}
# First pass through file
NR==FNR{
  if (index($0,"RegistrationsController#create") > 0) {
    pid=substr($3,2,length($3)-2);
  }
  recordcount=NR;
}
# Second pass through file
NR==recordcount+FNR{
  if (index($3,pid)==2) {
    count=count+1
    if (count==4 && index($0,"Completed 200 OK" > 0)) {
      success=1;
    }
  }
}
# Final pass through file
/stripe_card_token/{
  if (index($3,pid)==2 && success==1) {
    match($0,/(tok_[A-Za-z0-9]*)/);
    token=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
  }
}
END{
  print pid, count, success, token;
}
```

Usage:

```
awk -f gettoken.awk logfile logfile logfile
```

Comment: I am not completely able to understand the above script, but as far as I understood, it doesn't loops through the whole file if the 4th occurrence of that process ID doesn't contains 'Completed 200 OK'. It just stops and prints 'pid 0  '.
How to make it search the whole file?

Comment: In the second pass through the file, every record is examined. If, for a given record, the `pid` is correct, it checks for 'Completed 200 OK' and saves that fact in the `success` variable. if the 4th occurrence of `pid` does not contain the string, it keeps incrementing the count for every subsequent occurrence of that `pid`. If the `pid` is 0, it's because the script couldn't find it in the first pass through the file.

Comment: ohh ok,
so it searches the whole file with the first pid found? dont check the the file for next pid after getting done with the first one?

Comment: I didn't realize there would be more than one. You could change the script to use an array of pid's (and corresponding arrays of count, success and tokens). Do you need help with that?